# Uninstalled snapd with core system apps

Tags: apt, snap, 18.04, purge

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 I noticed high bandwidth traffic with the process `snapd` and since I don't use snap apps I decided to remove snap.

I used this command
`$ sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools`

and this is the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ubuntu-core-launcher' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-software-plugin-snap* snapd* squashfs-tools*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 57.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 317306 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (3.28.1-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing snapd (2.32.5+18.04) ...
Removing squashfs-tools (1:4.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
(Reading database ... 317244 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for snapd (2.32.5+18.04) ...
Stopping snap-communitheme-97.mount
Stopping unit snap-communitheme-97.mount
Waiting until unit snap-communitheme-97.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-communitheme-97.mount is stopped.
Removing snap communitheme and revision 97
Removing snap-communitheme-97.mount
Stopping snap-core-4486.mount
Stopping unit snap-core-4486.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core-4486.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core-4486.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core and revision 4486
Removing snap-core-4486.mount
Stopping snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
Stopping unit snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
Waiting until unit snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount is stopped.
Removing snap gnome-3-26-1604 and revision 59
Removing snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
Stopping snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
Stopping unit snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
Waiting until unit snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount is stopped.
Removing snap gnome-calculator and revision 154
Removing snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
Stopping snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
Stopping unit snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
Waiting until unit snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount is stopped.
Removing snap gnome-characters and revision 69
Removing snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
Stopping snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
Stopping unit snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
Waiting until unit snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount is stopped.
Removing snap gnome-logs and revision 25
Removing snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
Stopping snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
Stopping unit snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
Waiting until unit snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount is stopped.
Removing snap gnome-system-monitor and revision 36
Removing snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
Stopping snap-spotify-x1.mount
Stopping unit snap-spotify-x1.mount
Waiting until unit snap-spotify-x1.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-spotify-x1.mount is stopped.
Removing snap spotify and revision x1
Removing snap-spotify-x1.mount
Final directory cleanup
Discarding preserved snap namespaces
umount: /run/snapd/ns/vlc.mnt: not mounted.
Removing extra snap-confine apparmor rules
Removing snapd cache
Removing snapd state
```

I noticed that it removed core system apps. How can I undo the process again to restore snap and those apps again.

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Why not install the regular .deb versions of those “system apps”? (Spotify might not have a .deb package though.)

Comment: That was what I ended doing. Thanks alot @JanC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you erroneously uninstall core packages on an Ubuntu system it's possible to put the `deb` packages back simply with one command:-

**Note**: This presumes you previously installed the stock Ubuntu product, and not one of the other flavours.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

Once `snapd` is re-installed (which it should be with the above command), you can re-install the snaps which come pre-installed with:-

```
sudo snap install gnome-calculator
sudo snap install gnome-characters
sudo snap install gnome-logs
sudo snap install gnome-system-monitor
```

Simply repeat this process, or use the graphical Ubuntu Software for the additional snaps such as `communititheme`, `vlc` and others.